# Alignment of grid view in a layout to match all screen sizes

Tags: android, gridview

I'm making a hangman game and i have A to Z letters in my grid view in order to guess the word. The grid view is not aligning properly it is appearing in different sizes in different mobiles what i need is the grid view should match the height of the layout. Please help me to solve this 
.This is the problem i'm facing Please see the image below

[image]

I have took a relative layout for placing the grid view in it and it appears like shown in image,for small screen mobiles its automatically providing scroll option to scroll,and in big screen mobiles it is just going above the margin.
Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="270sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0sp">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/letters"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5sp"
        android:numColumns="9"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for matching the height you need do in code, get high of screen and divide that to rows and set to you grid items

Comment: how to get the height of the screen...?

Comment: @user3851899 - Here is a post that shows you how to get the screen size - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/1134429